# Constructing a vector of references from a 2d vector

Tags: rust, types, reference

I am trying to create a one dimensional vector which contains references to the elements of a 2d dimensional vector. This is because I later want to iteratively sort the elements of the grid and then perform some operations on the data.

So far I have tried something like the following

```rust
let mut grid: Vec<Vec<DataStruct>> = Vec::new();
// initialise the grid

let cell_stack: Vec<&DataStruct> = &field.into_iter.flatten.collect::<Vec<&DataStruct>();

for i in 0..cell_stack.len() {
  // sort 
  // some_func(cell_stack.pop());
}
```

However this doesn't work as the line creating `cell_stack` gives a datatype of `&Vec<DataStruct>` and the collect method is understandably not able to do its thing.

Any help would be appreciated or if I'm just approaching it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Rust doesn't allow you to store references to elements of a mutable vector. To be more specific, you *can* create a reference to an element, but you won't be able to modify the vector that holds that element *while* you are having that reference "alive". The reason for that is that vectors can grow and internally their elements might need to change their memory location.

So you might want to consider another approach. Sometimes storing the vector indexes might be a good approach (in your case, since you want to reference a "2D vector", you could store a tuple like `(usize, usize)`). Another way to go could be to use the [Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) struct (or another suitable [smart pointer type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html)) as a "wrapper" to each element in the 2D vector.

Comment: Storing references to mutable objects works just fine, you just can't modify the datastructure while it's borrowed.

Answer (score 1):

Once I cleaned all your syntax errors and use `iter` instead of `into_iter` this works like a charm:

```rust
struct DataStruct {}
fn main() {
    let mut grid: Vec<Vec<DataStruct>> = vec![vec![DataStruct{}], vec![DataStruct{}, DataStruct{}]];

    let mut cell_stack: Vec<&DataStruct> = grid.iter().flatten().collect();

    for i in 0..cell_stack.len() {
        // some_func(cell_stack.pop());
        cell_stack.pop();
        println!("{i}");
    }
}
```

But you can't change data in `grid` while it's borrowed this way. i.e until `cell_stack` is dropped.